# Confused about how to pass data / scope between directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>{{ product.current.name }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <form class="form">
      <div sa-product-general></div>
      <div sa-product-images></div>
      <div sa-product-buttons></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the `Controller As` syntax, so the main controller is called `product` and it sets a variable for `current`, which is the current product object.

Within the 3 directives in the form, I need access to that same product object.

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use shared or isolated scopes for this, and what the best way in general to handle it is.

Can you please help?

**Examples of the code:**

```
angular.module('saProducts').directive 'saProductPage', ->
  restrict: 'AE'
  templateUrl: 'app/products/product/product-page.html'
  controllerAs: 'product'
  controller: ($stateParams, $state, Product) ->
    @current = Product.get(id: $stateParams.id)
```

---

```
angular.module('saProducts').directive 'saProductButtons', ->
  restrict: 'AE'
  templateUrl: 'app/products/product/buttons.html'
  scope:
    currentProduct: '='
  controllerAs: 'productButtons'
  controller: ($scope, $state) ->
    @update = ->
      $scope.currentProduct.$update()

    @delete = ->
      $scope.currentProduct.$delete()
      $state.go('products')
```

**Update to the markup**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>{{ product.current.name }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <form class="form">
      <div sa-product-general></div>
      <div sa-product-buttons current-product="product.current"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**But these are undefined??**

```
angular.module('saProducts').directive 'saProductButtons', ->
  restrict: 'AE'
  templateUrl: 'app/products/product/buttons.html'
  scope:
    currentProduct: '='
  controllerAs: 'productButtons'
  controller: ($scope, $state) ->
    console.log @currentProduct
    console.log currentProduct
```

**THE ANSWER**

Use: `bindToController: true`

Comment: With the new code you posted, `$scope` is unnecessary.  since `currentProduct` is being passed to the scope, it is a property on the controller, it does not need to be referenced from the `$scope`.  also, since the controller is *isolated*, the name assigned through `controllerAs:` can be anything you want, even `product`, because it's not exposed to the outer scope.  In practice, however, your controllers should still have names that reflect their use.

Comment: @Claies this is what I'm looking for! But when I console.log currentProduct without calling it off of $scope, it says it's undefined?

Comment: even after adding `current-product="product.current"` to your directive in the HTML?

Comment: Yes, that's the way I'm able to get in on the $scope to begin with. But within the directive's controller, I can't access it directly.

Comment: hmm, that doesn't make sense.  you should have a property like `productButtons.currentProduct` that shouldn't be undefined?  inside the controller, you don't have to reference the controller by name, but even `this.currentProduct` should be populated....

Comment: I just posted the current state of the code.

Comment: Seems I needed to add `bindToController: true` since I'm using `controller as` syntax. It all works now. You should have answered this.. I would have awarded it to you! :-)

Comment: my answer wouldn't have been much different from the answer you accepted, and my interest is in being helpful, and learning something myself in the process, even through clarifying the issue in comments.  The points come naturally, but they aren't the main focus of things... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options here. The most sensible one is to use an isolated scope and a two way data binding for the product. So in the directive declaration something like:

```
app.directive('something', function() {
    return {
        scope:  {
             currentProduct: '='
        }
    }
})
```

Then the template:

```
<div something current-product="product.current"></div>
```

And once the directive compiles, currentProduct in the directive isolate scope is bound to product.current.

Comment: This helps, thank you. Do you know how I can maintain the `controller as` alias that I've used in the parent directive/controller for the children? The parent uses `product`, but now for the children I'm having to come up with hokey names. Like `productButtons` and so on.

Comment: Well, the idea is your directives don't know about the controller or what the controllerAs is. The involvement with the outer scope ends at the interface.

Comment: Ok, just posted some samples of the main directive and the child product buttons directive. Not sure if I'm doing this right.

Comment: That's right, but know that there is a big difference between the controller in the directive and the controller outside, and their respective controllerAs names. The isolate scope separates the controller inside entirely. You could give them the same name even.

Answer (score 1):

You have three main options:

1. Not use a directive - unless they are used more than once.
2. Use an isolated scope, and pass in the `product` object. I would use an element directive instead of an attribute directive.
3. Use a shared scope, and access the `product` in the same scope in each three directives.

Using one scope to rule them all causes the directives (in this case) to be less reusable, and less readable (in my opinion), because they demand a certain "interface" (a product object in the calling scope), without declaring about it.

I'd go with option #2